# GROUP BY DAYNAME doesn't include today's records?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a SQL statement to send day and sum, grouped by day, via PHP to a JavaScript chart via ajax. The statement does not return records from today, which do exist.

I've done a generic select to ensure there are records for today.

To recreate, you would need a table with a datetime `Created` field and an integer `price` field with records for the last 8 days including today.

Table

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Created | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price   | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample data

```
2019-08-12 23:04:03      7 
2019-08-13 00:22:20      7 
2019-08-13 22:41:13      7 
2019-08-13 23:23:23      7 
2019-08-13 23:37:27      7 
2019-08-14 03:53:29      7 
2019-08-14 23:15:22      7 
2019-08-14 23:44:17      7 
2019-08-14 23:52:01      7 
2019-08-15 00:24:47     20 
2019-08-15 00:24:49      7 
2019-08-15 00:45:53      7 
2019-08-16 22:03:01      7 
2019-08-16 23:13:03      7 
2019-08-16 23:28:25      7 
2019-08-16 23:43:05      7 
2019-08-17 00:26:22      7 
2019-08-17 00:32:38      7 
2019-08-17 00:41:14      7 
2019-08-17 04:45:11      7 
2019-08-17 06:38:33      7 
2019-08-17 08:55:23     20 
2019-08-17 09:13:39      7 
2019-08-17 23:12:00      7 
2019-08-17 23:54:23      7 
2019-08-18 00:26:11      7 
2019-08-18 23:28:21      7 
2019-08-18 23:28:54     20 
2019-08-19 00:52:18      7 
2019-08-19 10:19:58      7
```

Query

```
SELECT DAYNAME(Created) AS theday,SUM(price) AS thesum 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(Created) 
ORDER BY Created asc LIMIT 7;
```

I would expect the above to return the last 7 days of data including today, but it returns the last 7 days up to yesterday.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Furthermore, on today- Monday, the below query where the ,1 means start the week on Monday
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEARWEEK(Created,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW());
returns last week's results. Whereas
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEARWEEK(Created,0) = YEARWEEK(NOW());
which starts the week on Sunday, returns yesterday and today. Weird.

Comment: I suspect that the only 'furthermore' we're even vaguely interested in is the one that addresses the above, which should be provided as an edit to the question.

Comment: The query you posted does not even run: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEvkHadcKaNgcVra16ekfZ/0. How do you see results?

Comment: Runs just fine on my server.  Change the ORDER BY field to DAYNAME(Created) and it will run.


Run this in that fiddle.


SELECT DATE(Created),SUM(price) AS thesum 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY DATE(Created)
ORDER BY DATE(Created) asc LIMIT 7;

interestingly @Luke's suggestion of using desc does work in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is Order By 'Created' ASC, or ascending.  This means that records will be ordered by the 'Created' column in order from least to greatest.  Your results will list rows from 2019-08-12 at the top and rows from 2019-08-19 at the bottom.  Because there are 8 rows, and your are limiting the results to return 7, the rows from 2019-08-19 will not be displayed in the results.

Just replace 'ASC' with 'DESC' and you should get the results you want.

Comment: No joy - I can change order to desc and the limit to 70 and I still just get 12th to 18th.


SELECT Created,DAYNAME(Created) AS theday FROM mytable  ORDER BY Created DESC;


The output from the above includes entries from the 19th.

Comment: @FreddieAteMyHamster, try doing just a Select * from this table and tell me if the records from today show up.

Comment: So SELECT DATE(Created),SUM(price) AS thesum FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(Created) ORDER BY DATE(Created) desc LIMIT 7;
works fine, but SELECT DAYNAME(Created) AS theday,SUM(price) AS thesum FROM mytable GROUP BY DAYNAME(Created) ORDER BY Created desc LIMIT 7; does not. It seems that although the GROUP BY and ORDER by are both working on Created, the fact that one is processed by the DAYNAME function is causing the issue. Anyway I can work around this. I can reverse the array and get the daynames in PHP, so thanks for your help pinpointing what was wrong.